# Detecting text like "#smth" with RegExp (with some more terms)

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I'm really bad in regular expressions, so please help me.

I need to find in string any pieces like `#text`.

`text` mustn't contain any space characters (`\\s`). It's length must be at least 2 characters (`{2,}`), and it must contain at least 1 letter(`QChar::isLetter()`).

**Examples:**

- `#c`, `#1`, `#123456`, `#123 456`, `#123_456` are incorrect
- `#cc`, `#text`, `#text123`, `#123text` are correct

I use QRegExp.

Comment: What about `##text`? The second `#` is not a space character, so it passes the test. Should the regexp match the substring starting at the first or second `#` ? or perhaps both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styne666 gave the right regex.

Here is a little Perl script which is trying to match its first argument with this regex:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $arg = shift;
    if ($arg =~ m/(#(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{2,})/) {
        print "$1 MATCHES THE PATTERN!\n";
    } else {
        print "NO MATCH\n";
    }
```

Perl is always great to quickly test your regular expressions.

Now, your question is a bit different. You want to find all the substrings in your text string,
and you want to do it in C++/Qt. Here is what I could come up with in couple of minutes:

```
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include <QRegExp>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QString str = argv[1];
        QRegExp rx("[\\s]?(\\#(?=\\d*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\\d]{2,})\\b");

        int pos = 0;
        while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1)
        {
            QString token = rx.cap(1);
            cout << token.toStdString().c_str() << endl;
            pos += rx.matchedLength();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

To make my test I feed it an input like this (making a long string just one command line argument):

```
    peter@ubuntu01$ qt-regexp "#hjhj  4324   fdsafdsa  #33e #22"
```

And it matches only two words: **#hjhj** and **#33e**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
QRegExp rx("#(\\S+[A-Za-z]\\S*|\\S*[A-Za-z]\\S+)$");
bool result = (rx.indexIn(str) == 0);
```

rx either finds a non-whitespace followed by a letter and by an unspecified number of non-whitespace characters, or a letter followed by at least non-whitespace.

Comment: #123text matches #\\S+[A-Za-z]\\S*

Comment: Missed the capitalisation! Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest I could come up with (which *should* work, but I haven't tested extensively) is:

```
QRegExp("^#(?=[0-9]*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$");
```

Which matches:

- `^` the start of the string
- `#` a literal hash character
- `(?=` then look ahead (but don't match)

  - `[0-9]*` zero or more latin numbers
  - `[A-Za-z]` a single upper- or lower-case latin letter
- `)`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}` then match at least two characters which may be upper- or lower-case latin letters or latin numbers
- `$` then find and consume the end of the line

Technically speaking though this is still wrong. It only matches latin letters and numbers. Replacing a few bits gives you:

```
QRegExp("^#(?=\\d*[^\\d\\s])\\w{2,}$");
```

This should work for non-latin letters and numbers but this is totally untested. Have a quick read of the [QRegExp class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QRegExp.html) for an explanation of each escaped group.

And then to match within larger strings of text (again, untested):

```
QRegExp("\b#(?=\\d*[^\\d\\s])\\w{2,}\b");
```

A useful tool is the [Regular Expressions Example](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/tools-regexp.html) which comes with the SDK.

Comment: I don't think the anchoring is intended. "Find in string" suggests that the regexp should match `#text` inside `"This is a #text example"`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after I did example 2, hence example 3.

Answer (score -1):

use this regular expression. hope fully your problem will solve with given RE.

```
^([#(a-zA-Z)]+[(a-zA-Z0-9)]+)*(#[0-9]+[(a-zA-Z)]+[(a-zA-Z0-9)]*)*$
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 1) Doesn't match "#". 2) Matches a zero length string.

Comment: Dear @Styne666 
# is not a big deal in this RE. and Matches a zero length: u will also check your input as a null or not.